# Is it possible to relocate the Resharper ShellCaches folder (not Solution Caches)?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I think the excessive access to the files in this folder plus the aggressive anti virus installed by our beloved IT department are the root cause for the severe performance penalty I see when working with R#.

We have a "shelter" folder bypassed by the Anti Virus, so I wonder whether it is possible to move the ShellCaches folder there?

The actual directory path is `%LOCALAPPDATA%\JetBrains\Transient\ReSharperPlatformVs12\v03\ShellCaches\Shell\Db\`

Note, that I do not want to relocate the entire `%LOCALAPPDATA%` at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to move ShellCaches folder.NTFS supports junctions.

Steps to move:

1. move `%LOCALAPPDATA%\JetBrains\Transient\ReSharperPlatformVs12\v03\ShellCaches\Shell\Db` to some Target. (For Example  to `c:\shelter\ResharperCache`)
2. Call in Command Promt: `mklink /J %LOCALAPPDATA%\JetBrains\Transient\ReSharperPlatformVs12\v03\ShellCaches\Shell\Db\ TARGET`

Or you can use [Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html) to create a Junction with drag&drop.

Comment: The problem is that junction may still be treated as a normal directory by an anti-virus, which may apply the same aggressive scan despite the actual location of the files in the "shelter".  I need that directory completely vanished from the anti-virus sight.

Comment: In fact, I am pretty sure it does not help, because R# continues to access the files using the old paths, meaning the anti-virus would see manipulation of files outside of the "shelter". It does not matter that the files are physically under "shelter" - all anti-virus care about is that an access is made to "unsheltered" location and hence it triggers its logic.

Comment: You right, sorry. I was thinking about a space as i wrote it. This folder was 19G on my system.